# How can I add autocomplete "Candidate Users, Candidate Groups" for User Task?

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, bpmn.io

i'm beginner in **bpmn** ,i created human task , how can add autocomplete in Candidate Users, Candidate Groups fileds it's possible? autocomplete from list ,active directory, ... .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The properties panel is just a minimal example and has no built in data binding.

However, it is itself highly flexible in what content is displayed and this is where you can start to develop your custom data provider.

There are not really tutorials out there on how to write a custom data provider for your properties panel but you can make use of the following example from the official examples repository:

[bpmn-js-examples/properties-panel-extension/](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-examples/tree/master/properties-panel-extension)

It is quite complex and takes some time to understand just from the code and the spare documentation but let me tell you, that this is the place to look at if you want to write your custom data provider.

If you get stuck at a specific point, you can create a new question here on SO with a concrete code example.